# How to create a Localizable.strings for several languages in xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode

How to create a `Localizable.strings` for several languages in xcode 4.5?

It seems the "add a new language" button has missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Localizable.strings file, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to open the right menu. There's a `Make localized...` button in Localization (File inspector tab). Then you can add any language as you want.